# Database rawQuery not return all my data

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to print all of my data from my columns in the Sqlite database but I get only one column instead of my two columns.

```
    mHelper = new TaskDbHelper(BackgroundProcess.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor ti = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "tasks", null);
    if ( ti.moveToFirst() ) {
        do {
            Log.d("Test1","col: " + ti.getString(1));
        } while (ti.moveToNext());
    }
```

My database Fields - Title and Place

the code result is -

Test1: col: test Title 1

Test1: col: test Title 2

not print the place files

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read all elements, you'll have the use multiple indices for the *getString()* method:

```
// The index in the 'get...'-method determines the column
String title = cursor.getString(0);
String place = cursor.getString(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You got all columns, but you have printed just second column.

See the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29